# Why does my React component key return undefined when a number is passed as it's prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to have a grid of components, and save data about the state of every component on that grid, to achieve this I tried using an array of objects that would correspond to every component on the grid, that array is initialized as such:

```js
let count = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < 30; j++){
      count++;
      let x = 0;
      if(i % 2 !== 0){
        x = j * WIDTH_OF_CELL + OFFSET_X;
      } else {
        x = j * WIDTH_OF_CELL + OFFSET_X + 24;
      }
      const y = i * HEIGHT_OF_CELL + OFFSET_Y;

      let cell = {
        y: y,
        x: x,
        centerX: x + 25,
        centerY: y + 25,
        state: 0,
        key: count
      }
      cellsGrid.push(cell);
    }
  }
```

And then to actualy render the components an itermediate component takes the `cellsGrid` array as a prop and maps every object to a cell component:

```js
return (
    <div>
      {cellsGrid.map((item) => 
        <Cell 
        key={item.key} 
        postitX={item.x} 
        postitY={item.y} 
        edit={edit} 
        state={item.state} 
        handleClick={handleClick}>
        </Cell>
      )}
    </div>
)
```

The `state` property represents if a cell is on or off, it's initialized to `0`, and when a cell is clicked it should be updated to `1`, to do that a `handleClick` function is passed down to the cell component as a prop:

```js
const handleClick = (event, state, key, callback) => {
    callback();
    let index = cellsGrid.findIndex(cell => cell.key === key);
    cellsGrid[index].state = state;
  };
```

Inside the cell component `handleClick` is passed values based on it's inner state, the key of the cell that was just clicked, along with it's state, since every cell component is created using the  `cellsGrid` array, the key of a cell should correspond to the key of the array object that generated it:

```js
onClick={event => handleClick(event, currentState.state, key, nextState)}
```

But when a cell is clicked the console throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'state')

I tried logging the values of `key` and `index` inside the `handleClick` function:

```js
const handleClick = (event, state, key, callback) => {
    callback();
    let index = cellsGrid.findIndex(cell => cell.key === key);
    //cellsGrid[index].state = state;
    console.log(key);
    console.log(index);
  };
```

> **Outputs:**
>
> `undefined`
>
> `-1`

I don't understand why `key` is undefined, it's meant to be the same key as the object in the `cellsGrid` array, so I can find the object and update it's `state`. Sorry if the code looks rough, I'm new to React and javascript, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: instead of using let count > try cellsGrid.map((item, index) => and set key={index}. if key is undefined

Comment: Changing the name of the property from `key` to `index` solved it, doing this also allowed me to skip calling `cellsGrid.findIndex`, since the index is passed to the `handleClick` function by the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use key as a prop. Key is not passed as a prop. Key is used by react internally to help optimize rendering of the nodes
You can pass index as a prop like

```
<MyComponent index={item.key}

props.index would have the value.
```